# Assassins Creed: Rogue DLC for PS3 not showing in Inventory

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-rogue

I have bought the new Assassins Creed: Rogue for PS3 and was very excited to play it and redeem the DLC pack. I have punched in the code and according to the instructions, would show up after Sequence 3 Memory 4. I am at either Sequence 4 or 5 and I still cannot see it in my Inventory. Does anyone know what more I have to do after I downloaded the DLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the Limited Edition DLC (Pre-Order Bonus), then go to the southeast area of the North Atlantic and sail to where the symbol DS is (hexagonal shape). Once you're there, you'll be prompted to select a location. Select Fort De Sable and you'll load into the area. You'll have an objective to loot the three chests, which contain the DLC items. I think that it's the same for the other DLC, but in different areas of the world. For Sir Gunn's Armour, I believe it has something to do with collecting Templar Crosses scattered throughout the world. Odds are, if you've explored the North Atlantic, you've already found your DLC. It *has* been 8 days now, as of me reading this. Anyway, I hope this is of some help.